# Getting an error Error: 1:32: unexpected '/' in Rstudio when trying to knit [SOLVED]

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I can't knit. I've tried uninstalling the Rstudio, but it didn't work. When I try to knit I get the following error.

```
Error: 1:32: unexpected '/'
1: options(repos = c(CRAN = https:/
Execution halted
```

This is my code:

````
---
title: "S22"
output:
  word_document: default
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
date: '2022-06-13'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


Učitavamo .csv datoteku:
```{r}
e88_sk<-read.csv("edukacija88.csv", header = T)
fix(e88_sk)


```
````

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFEpH.png]

[SOLUTION]
I've solved it by running this command in the console:

```
file.edit(file.path("~", ".Rprofile")) # edit .Rprofile in HOME
```

And then by editing the .Rprofile by replacing

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = https://cran.rstudio.com))
```

With

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cran.rstudio.com"))
```

Comment: Could you please share some code you used?

Comment: Perhaps you need some quotes around the link `"https:/..."`

Comment: e.g. `unname(options()$repos)#
[1] "https://cloud.r-project.org"` it is a quoted string, so when you try to change the repos with unquoted value, it returns error

Comment: I added the code, but I don't think it's the code since the same code ran normally a month ago